# iPhone - Global Variable In A Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to have a global array/variable in an iPhone app that uses storyboard. Is there a way to access such a global variable from a number of different storyboard screens?

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storyboard part is somewhat irrelevant: the standard way of achieving this in cocoa is to define a *singleton* object as your model, share its header among the controllers defined in your application (through storyboard or otherwise) and create an instance of your shared model in the application start-up code.

For information on implementing singletons in Objective C read [this link](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/).

Comment: *Just asking*: can't we declare those variables in Appdelegate file and use it in every class?

Comment: I would appreaciate if you throw some light on that.

Comment: @anonymous Technically you can put it in any file, and Appdelegate is neither better nor worse in this respect. However, it is not the most typical choice for placing your model. The best choice for shared variables is an appropriately named shared class in a common location.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you, I will look into singletons which also seem like a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the easiest one is to store the information in NSUserDefaults. It will be accessible everywhere in the app, so that should be what you want. I am posting a snippet, if you don't know how to work with it :)

How to set it:

```
NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL yourVariable = YES;
[settings setBool:yourVariable forKey:@"myVariableKey"];
[settings synchronize];
```

How to get it:

```
NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL yourVariable = [settings boolForKey:@"myVariableKey"];
```

I am posting an example with boolean, but it can be whatever value you need  - for example:

```
[settings setValue:@"Hello!" forKey:@"welcomeMessage"];
```

Comment: Thank you, works great!! 

If I release the NSUserDefault object, that free up the space where the item is being saved on a permanent basis, I presume?